# Iphone app only won't run at the right resolution on ipad

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode6, resolution

The app only displays the top left corner of the game on the ipad but on iphone it runs fine. this is an iphone only game but my app keeps getting rejected because its a requirement for the iphone app to run 2x iphone quality on ipad. any help would be amazing i've been stuck on this. [image: iphone6][image: ipad]

Comment: You surely are using AutoLayout and you've added a different layout for different size classes. Btw, I didn't know Oprah could code :P

Answer (score 0):

please check that in your Target you have choose the app type only for iPhone see attached screenshot.
If you not select your app only for iPhone,the appstore check it for Universal and cause 2x Image issue.

NOTE: also check if you have select Autolayout or Autoresize option or not

[image]

Comment: do i want autoresize/autolayout